# How could I reduce the length of this code?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to reduce the length of this code in Python3 as much as possible (even if it will be less readable):

```
a,b,x,y=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
while 1: 
 r=''
 if y<b:r='S';y+=1
 if y>b:r='N';y-=1 
 if x<a:r+='E';x+=1
 if x>a:r+='W';x-=1
 print(r)
```

It's a map: you are on (x,y) and you need to go to (a,b) 
S for South
N for North
NE for North East....
After each turn I must tell where to go using print.

For example could I put all the if on one line ?

Comment: I don't think you can do to shorten this code.  `while 1` should probably be `while (a,b) != (x,y)` though.

Comment: It's a game and when the character is on a,b, it will automatically stop

Comment: You might want to ask this question on code golf.

Answer (score 0):

```
a,b,x,y=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
print('S'*(b-y)+'N'*(y-b)+'E'*(a-x)+'W'*(x-a))
```

This relies on `'W' * 3 == 'WWW'` and `'W' * -3 == ''`. The ordering of the directions will not be the same as the original code (it won't interleave multiple N/Ses with multiple E/Wes). Also unlike the original code, it won't go into an infinite loop once you hit the goal.

Comment: Thank you but I need an "optimal angle": i have to use 'SE','NW'.... and I have to print one direction at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is actually *longer*, but it works and by god it's too ugly to not share.

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest
a,b,x,y=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
[ print(''.join(x)) for x in zip_longest(chain(('N' for _ in range(b, y)), ('S' for _ in range(b, y, -1))), chain(('W' for _ in range(a, x)), ('E' for _ in range (a, x, -1))), fillvalue='') ]
```